# 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' google maps MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps

I want to display the Google maps with the following code using iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
<noscript>
    <div style="display: inline;">
      <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style: none;" alt="" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/''/?label='';guid=ON&amp;script=0" />
    </div>
</noscript>
    <div class="mapContainer" style="width: 251px; height: 202px;">
       <iframe id="iGmap" width="251" height="202" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentBranch.GoogleMapURLWithZoomSet)">
       </iframe>
    </div>
```

Where

```
src='http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=''&amp;ll='',''&amp;spn='',''&amp;output=embed&amp;z=4'
```

The above code I am using in cshtml page
But giving the error like Refused to display 'https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=…&ll=,&spn=,&output=embed&z=6' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and resolve it by adding this `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true` to `protected void Application_Start()` method in my Global.asax.

That should resolve it.